# How can I implement "copy & pasting" to Finder using NSPasteboard?

Tags: swift, macos, nspasteboard

I implemented copy and pasting using NSPasteboard and FilePromise within my app. Now I'd like to implement the following workflow.

1. Copy an item in my app.

```
let provider = NSFilePromiseProvider(fileType: kUTTypeVideo as String, delegate: self)
```

2. Open Finder
3. Paste the item to Finder using the mouse context menu.

I'm stuck at the step 3. Finder doesn't recognize the items I added to the pasteboard so there's no "Paste Item' menu in the context menu.

Please note that this is not a drag-and-drop. With drag-and-drop, the following delegate is called just fine.

```
func filePromiseProvider(_ filePromiseProvider: NSFilePromiseProvider, writePromiseTo url: URL, completionHandler: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {
```

Could someone give me a pointer?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use NSPasteboard with kPasteboardTypeFileURLPromise for copy/paste?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58886232/how-to-use-nspasteboard-with-kpasteboardtypefileurlpromise-for-copy-paste)

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have the same problem and the above mentioned reference doesn't have a solution either.